# Login and registration with sharedpreferences. android mobile

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, mobile, sharedpreferences

I made a simple registration login application but 'error running register: the activity' register_ol 'is not declared in androidManifest.xml

public class kayit_ol extends AppCompatActivity {

```
 private  EditText editTextAd;
private  EditText editTextSoyad;
private  EditText editTextMail;
private  EditText editTextSifre;
private  EditText editTextSifretek;
private  EditText editTextCep;
private Button buttonYenikayit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kayit_ol);


    editTextAd=findViewById(R.id.editTextAd);
    editTextSoyad=findViewById(R.id.editTextSoyad);
    editTextMail=findViewById(R.id.editTextMail);
    editTextSifre=findViewById(R.id.editTextSifre);
    editTextSifretek=findViewById(R.id.editTextSifretek);
    editTextCep=findViewById(R.id.editTextCep);
    buttonYenikayit=findViewById(R.id.buttonYenikayit);

    buttonYenikayit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("Kaydım",MODE_PRIVATE);
            String kullanıcıadı=editTextAd.getText().toString();
            String soyad =editTextSoyad.getText().toString();
            String mail =editTextMail.getText().toString();
            String sifre=editTextSifre.getText().toString();
            String sifretek=editTextSifretek.getText().toString();
            String cep=editTextCep.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
            editor.putString(kullanıcıadı+soyad+sifre+sifretek+cep+"Kayit",kullanıcıadı+"\n"+mail);
            editor.commit();

            Intent girisekrani=new Intent(kayit_ol.this, com.faikmermer.a173311103_fmermer.girisekrani.class);
            startActivity(girisekrani);
        }
    });

}
```

}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public class girisekrani extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private EditText editTextkullanıcıad;
private EditText editTextkullanicisifre;
private Button buttongiris;
private Button buttonKayit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_girisekrani);


    editTextkullanıcıad=findViewById(R.id.editTextkullanıcıad);
    editTextkullanicisifre=findViewById(R.id.editTextkullanicisifre);
    buttongiris=findViewById(R.id.buttongiris);
    buttonKayit=findViewById(R.id.buttonKayit);

   buttongiris.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           String kullanıcı=editTextkullanıcıad.getText().toString();
           String sifre=editTextkullanicisifre.getText().toString();

           SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("Kaydım",MODE_PRIVATE);

           String kullanıcıbilgisi=preferences.getString(kullanıcı+sifre+"Kayit","Kullanıcı Adi ve Şifre Hatalıdırç");
           SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();

           editor.putString("girisekrani",kullanıcıbilgisi);

           editor.commit();

           Intent anaekran=new Intent(girisekrani.this,MainActivity.class);
           startActivity(anaekran);
       }
   });

   buttonKayit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent kayitEkrani=new Intent(girisekrani.this,kayit_ol.class);
           startActivity(kayitEkrani);
       }
   });

}
```

}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("Kaydım",MODE_PRIVATE);
    String girisekrani=preferences.getString("girisekrani"," ");
}
```

}
              ///////////////////////////////////////

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".kayit_ol"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".girisekrani" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".kayit_ol"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".girisekrani"></activity>


</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare activity classes in the android manifest file, like it's done with Main activity but without the launcher filter. This can be done automatically when you create a new activity class using the activity gallery.

Your AndroidManifest should look like this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".kayit_ol"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".girisekrani" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".register_ol"></activity>


</application>
```